# MS-Project JavaScript Add-In

Tags: ms-project

I'm new to Javascript and trying to create a Microsoft Project add-in for fun.  If I want my add-in to do something as simple as look at the 'Text1' field of each task and count how many tasks in a project contain the word "Yes" in that field, what is an easy way to accomplish this?  Would I use the getTaskFieldAsync method to look at the Text1 field of each task or is there a better option?

I'm running Project 2013.

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? If you could provide any code that you have tried already it can help us with answering your question.

Comment: Why would you use JavaScript to build an Add-In? The intellisense with VB.Net or C# using the free version of Visual Studio is going to make things much, much easier. Plus there is a vastly larger base of existing knowledge to work with.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll look into using those tools instead of JavaScript.  I am just following Microsoft's quick start guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart), that is how I started down this path.  And I am using VS Code.

Comment: Hi Timothy.  The code I have so far was just a proof of concept, where I could click a button to get the task GUID and then a second button to get some information about the selected task (in this case the Number8 field).  Is there a place I can put my code for you to see?